# Why is my setInterval in my test case not running?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, wait, react-testing-library

I created a timer component that uses a setInterval to change the time to be displayed. The timer is working but when I create a test file for it, the setInterval does not get executed.

I tried looking into the test library and saw that I can add interval and timeout and tried that but did not work. I am not sure why this is happening.

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timeLeft:300
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.startTimer();  
  }

  startTimer = () => {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      var time = this.state.timeLeft;
      time--;
      this.setState({ timeleft: time });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() { 
    ...some logic for mins and seconds

    return (
      <span data-testid='timer-id'>
        {min}:{seconds}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Test

```
describe("...", () => {
  it('should count down', async () => {
    const {container} = render(<Timer />);
    await wait(() => getByTestId(container, 'timer-id'));
  });
});
```

I expect that test case to cover the interval part of the timer, however it only shows that the setInterval is called but the inside code is not being executed

**Edit**: Okay I think I solved it. I had to change my test case to

```
describe("...", () => {
  it('should count down', async () => {
    const {container} = render(<Timer />);
    await wait(() => {
      const timer = getByTestId(container, 'timer-id');
      expect(timer).toEqual('04:59');
    )};
  });
});
```

I guess it found the first instance of it and returned the result before the setInterval had a change to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing an object, instead of a function

```
this.timer = setInterval(() => {
  var time = this.state.timeLeft;
  time--;
  this.setState({ timeleft: time });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code. I made a typo and that the setInterval is a function

Comment: what testing library are you using?

Comment: React Testing Library